# string value is lost after encryption

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am encrypting my value before saving to database my piece of code is

```
 EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('SKEDB_BenName_11'), cast((FirstName + ' ' + Surname) as nvarchar)) ,

AccountName = EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('SKEDB_BenName_11'),UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(@AccountName))))
```

This code is working properly when @AccountName string length is upto 26 if the length above the 26 then it encrypt the string up to 26 value I want encryption of full value. Please Suggest

Comment: *Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)* https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will default to 30
    cast((FirstName + ' ' + Surname) as nvarchar))

That is, [nvarchar/varchar will default to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql)

- 30 in CAST
- 1 in other cases

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified with the CAST function, the default length is 30

If you want up to, say 100, use

```
cast((FirstName + ' ' + Surname) as nvarchar(100)))
```

Comment: Your question has 2  different EncryptByKey calls. I've fixed only the obvious error: your code is incomplete, for example how do you generate @AccountName